# ASP.NET Label removing spaces

Tags: asp.net

Is this a fault in ASP.NET 4.0, or am I missing something obvious...?

I have a `<asp:Repeater>` with the following lines within the `<ItemTemplate>`...

```
<td><asp:Checkbox runat="server" ID="chkInclude" Checked="true" /></td>
<td>
  <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="chkInclude">
    <%#Container.DataItem.FirstName%> <%#Container.DataItem.Surname%></asp:Label>
</td>
```

This results in the firstname and surname being rendered **without** a space between...

```
<td>JoeBlogs</td>
```

There's a simple solution, which is to concatenate the strings...

```
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="chkInclude">
  <%#Container.DataItem.FirstName & " " & Container.DataItem.Surname%></asp:Label>
```

... but I'd like to know why the space is being stripped out of the `<asp:Label>` when using individual `<%#Container%>` elements.  I can't see an obvious attribute on the control that would suggest this can be overridden.

---

As pointed out in a now-deleted comment, I could also add `&nbsp;` between the elements as another work-around... but this would stop it word-wrapping if appropriate.

---

Further investigation (prompted by @Andrei) shows that...

- Removing the `<asp:Label>` results in correct output
- Replacing the `<%#%>` blocks with hard-text results in correct output
- Adding hard-text between the `<%#%>` blocks results in correct output (although I obviously don't want the extra text)
- Replacing the `<asp:Label>` with straight `<span>` results in correct output

But have two blocks with single space, and it fails (i.e. no space between).

I also tried removing the `AssociatedControlID` but that also failed.

Comment: If multiple spaces were replaced with one space, it would be due to how HTML is rendered. But single space removed looks really strange. Have you tried simplifying things? Say instead of `<%# %>` just hardcode stuff and see what happens? Or even replace Label with span and again see what happens?

Comment: @Andrei - agreed, it is strange. Removing the `<asp:Label>` completely is fine... replacing the `<%#%>` blocks with hard-text is fine... adding text between the `<%#%>` blocks is fine.  But have two blocks with single space, and it fails.  I also tried removing the `AssociatedControlID`  but that also failed.  In the end, it's not that important, as I have a simple work-around, I just thought it was something I was doing wrong and wanted to check

Comment: Nothing you are doing wrong, but that would be fun to figure out. So what I would try is: 1) No containers: `<asp:Label>Joe Blogs</asp:Label>`; 2) No label control `<span> <%# Container %> <%# Container %> </span>`. Can you check if any of this retains the space?

Comment: @Andrei - 1) see the 2nd item in the list at the end of the edit. 2) see newly added 4th item in the list.  (i.e. both results in correct text).  Certainly **looks** like a fault within the `<asp:Label>` control

Comment: @Andrei, if you haven't seen it, Adrian has provided an [excellent answer that explains it perfectly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37001969/930393)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time I want to see how ASP .Net generates the code from the aspx markup I create a compilation error on purpose and then I check *Show Complete Compilation Source*.

I this case you could write something like

```
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="chkInclude">
    <%#Container.DataItem.FirstName / 2%> <%#Container.DataItem.Surname%></asp:Label>
```

Then you will see how ASP .Net parses what's between  `<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="chkInclude">` and `</asp:Label>`.

ASP .Net thinks here are two types of tokens: **static strings** and **data bound strings**. It stores them in two different arrays from which it builds, in this case, the Text property of the label control or it renders the html content in the Render method. The problem you have is that ASP .Net it doesn't consider the space between two data bound strings as a static string so it doesn't put that space in the array with the static strings. Once you add any char between these two data bound strings that becomes a static string, including the spaces.

[image]

In this image the blue marked texts are *data bound strings* and what's between them is a *static string*.

---

This happens with [DataBoundLiteralControl](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/UI/DataBoundLiteralControl.cs)

Comment: Fantastic - nicely found, and nicely explained.  That makes complete sense. Thank you :-)